# ScriptControlDescriptor.AddProperty & Read-Only Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, client-side, servercontrols

I'm creating an ASP.NET Server Control with an associated client-side API.

In my GetScriptDescriptors() method I'm associating a property called "rows"...

```
descriptor.AddProperty("rows", this.IntRows);
```

In my client-side API I want my "rows" property to be read-only...

```
MyControl = function(element)
{
    MyControl.initializeBase(this, [element]);
    this._rows;
}

MyControl.prototype =
{
    initialize: function()
    {
        MyControl.callBaseMethod(this, 'initialize');
    },

    get_rows: function()
    {
        return this._rows;
    },

    dispose: function()
    {
        MyControl.callBaseMethod(this, 'dispose');
    }
}
```

However this causes the following error...

> Error: Sys.InvalidOperationException:
>   'rows' is not a writable property.

The following setter seems to be required in order for the $create statement to assign "rows" it's initial value:

```
set_rows: function(value)
{
    this._rows = value;
},
```

How can I make the "rows" property read-only in the client-side API if the setter is required to assign the value from the AddProperty call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest method would be to have the set_rows ignore any input. Effectively this should stop the Exception from occurring altogether and still provide Read Only functionality to the property.

```
set_rows: function(value)
{
    value = null;
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I haven't had chance to test it yet. However I'm not sure I follow your sample. Wouldn't that simply clear the "rows" value if the setter was called?

Comment: @Poz Your correct it would. I set the wrong option to null. The other alternative would be to throw a not implemented exception, however that will need to be handled by the coder. Rather just silently ignore the set.